# Linux: Is there a filesystem that can stand an abrupt storage device disconnection?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, ssd, filesystems, sd-card

This may be more appropriate in UNIX & Linux, so please let me know. I'm wondering if there's a filesystem available in Linux that can withstand (or is designed to be able to better handle) hard disconnections of SSD/flash media? A good runner-up answer would be the suggestion of a filesystem mount parameter configuration that, with proper tuning, can be best prepared for disconnection events.

To make my use-case clear, an example would be removing a *mounted* SD Card without going through a software/OS unmounting process. Thanks!

Comment: I've had no trouble yanking out Linux "Live" disks where there's no persistence... of course, there's nothing being written to the flash drive since it's mounted RO. You could also use a flash card (in a USB card-reader, if necessary, since not all PC's can boot from an SD slot), with the RO slider set.

Comment: I used to have a laptop where the CD drive was a replaced by a HDD in a tray. The tray lock was broken and the tray could fall out, which it did in several occasions. The ext4 FS always survived the ordeal.

Comment: Any journaled file system (e.g. `ext4`, also others) should survive this, and be able to restore the state at the beginning of the interrupted transaction. You can fine tune the journalling options with `tunefs` etc.

Answer (score 1):

This is a scary topic, with a few avenues to investigate... I'm going to cover the two big ones.

Have a look at this talk from ELC 2015: *[Filesystem considerations for embedded devices](https://events.static.linuxfound.org/sites/events/files/slides/fs-for-embedded-full_0.pdf)*.

### Filesystem

The filesystem needs to handle writes to the disk carefully. An issue may present itself if, for example, the file's length is extended first, and data is written second. This is a problem that can readily occur, and I was reviewing a log file just today that exhibited this issue - the system unexpectedly lost power:

```
00017ea0  6f 74 29 20 43 4d 44 20  28 20 20 20 63 64 20 2f  |ot) CMD (   cd /|
00017eb0  20 26 26 20 72 75 6e 2d  70 61 72 74 73 20 2d 2d  | && run-parts --|
00017ec0  72 65 70 6f 72 74 20 2f  65 74 63 2f 63 72 6f 6e  |report /etc/cron|
00017ed0  2e 68 6f 75 72 6c 79 29  0a 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |.hourly)........|
00017ee0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00017ef0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00017f00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00017f10  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00017f20  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00017f30  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00017f40  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00017f50  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00017f60  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00017f70  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00017f80  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00017f90  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00017fa0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00017fb0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00017fc0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00017fd0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00017fe0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00017ff0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00018000  4d 61 72 20 31 30 20 31  35 3a 31 38 3a 33 34 20  |Mar 10 15:18:34 |
00018010  72 6f 6c 6c 79 20 72 73  79 73 6c 6f 67 64 3a 20  |rolly rsyslogd: |
00018020  5b 6f 72 69 67 69 6e 20  73 6f 66 74 77 61 72 65  |[origin software|
```

So yes... the filesystem must be able to handle such events. There are commercial offerings for filesystems that provide resiliance to power loss, but it's not my place to recommend one.

Of course, using a read-only filesystem as much as possible is a big benefit - for example having the OS on a read-only filesystem, and the configuration (etc...) on a read-write filesystem. This could potentially help you to recover from corruption and resume service.

Additionally, journalled filesystems will [typically handle such events better](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/12700/221985), but don't assume any level of guarantee... my log file above was on an `ext4` filesystem with journalling.

### Storage Medium

You mention SD cards as the underlying storage... which is concerning. In fact all flash storage has issues with losing power unexpectedly. This is due to the way they work - wear levelling is handled entirely by the storage controller, and as such it can decide to move pages around whenever it wants.

Additionally, a write to a page often consists of a whole set of operations, and there is no guarantee / standard to dictate which order they occur.

1. Check for an erased/new page - erasing one if necessary
2. Read data from old page
3. Apply modifications as per `write()`
4. Write new page
5. Re-link logical to physical mapping

There are many stories of people unplugging systems or storage devices and finding "*My 128GB SSD appears as 1GB*" or "*My SD card doesn't work any more*", etc...

A quote from JEDEC 84-A441: (admittedly referring to eMMC, but likely relevant)

> Resetting a card (using CMD0, CMD15, or hardware reset for e•MMC) or power failure will terminate
>   any pending or active programming operation. This may leave some or all of the data addressed by the
>   operation in an unknown state unless Reliable Write was enabled. It is the host’s responsibility to prevent this.

### Summary

Unfortunately there aren't really any good / reliable steps you can take to facilitate "*removing a mounted SD Card without going through a software/OS unmounting process*" and not running into problems.

Moral of the story - figure out a way to `sync` and `unmount` it correctly to ensure that filesystem data is contiguous, and that no `write()`s are in progress when the user does disconnect it.

Answer (score 0):

RFS - a Samsung file system "Robust File System" should be OK for this.

In practice, you should be able to use any journalled filesystem or system that does copy-on-write (ext3, ext4 and even more-so btrfs).  The risk you run - which will apply to any filesystem - is that the OS may buffer the information, or may not be finished writing when you pull the disk - in which case any information not finished being written won't be stored (but the existing data won't be corrupted, or, if it is, it can be replayed from the journal.